# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time in cakephp 2.6.7

Tags: rest, cakephp

A simple request was working fine. Here is the code snippet.

```
 $link = 'http://www.api2apipro.live/' . 'rest_payments.json';

    $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();

    $response = $httpSocket->post($link, $this->request->data);
```

Here `$this->request->data` is an array. Now it shows the following error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I found the reason. I can't browse http://www.api2apipro.live from my ip meaning I am not allowed to access this url from my local server. But is there any tricks to unlock this access grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server does not allow your IP from accessing the content, then you have no other option than running the script from the allowed IPs, or get your local IP authorised.